# How to load data into Apache Cassandra with Datastax Bulk loader (Ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, datastax, bulkloader, dsbulk

When I want to upload data to my "Test Cluster" into Apache Cassandra I open the terminal and then:

```
export PATH=/home/mypc/dsbulk-1.7.0/bin:$PATH

source ~/.bashrc

dsbulk load -url /home/mypc/Desktop/test/file.csv -k keyspace_test -t table_test
```

But...

```
At least 1 record does not match the provided schema.mapping or schema.query. Please check that the connector configuration and the schema configuration are correct.
Operation LOAD_20201105-103000-577734 aborted: Too many errors, the maximum allowed is 100.

total | failed | rows/s | p50ms | p99ms | p999ms | batches
  104 |    104 |      0 |  0,00 |  0,00 |   0,00 |    0,00

Rejected records can be found in the following file(s): mapping.bad
Errors are detailed in the following file(s): mapping-errors.log
Last processed positions can be found in positions.txt
```

What does it means? Why I can't load?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The error is that you're not providing the mapping between CSV data & table. It could be done 2 ways:

1. If CSV file has header with column names matching to the column names in Cassandra, then use `-header true`
2. Provide mapping explicitly using the `-m` option (see [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/schemaOptions.html?hl=mapping#schemaOptions__schemaMapping)) - you need to map CSV columns into Cassandra columns.

There is a very good series of the blog posts about different aspects of DSBulk usage:

- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/03/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-common-settings
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/06/datastax-bulk-loader-unloading
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/07/datastax-bulk-loader-counting
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/12/datastax-bulk-loader-examples-loading-other-locations

the first two of them covers data loading in great details

Answer (score 2):

It means that the columns in the CSV input file does not match the columns in your `table_test` table. You can get the details of the schema mismatch in the `mapping-errors.log` so you know which column(s) are problematic.

Since the CSV columns don't match the table schema, you will need to manually map them by specifying the `--schema.mapping` flag.

For details, see the [DSBulk Common options](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/commonOptions.html) page. You can also have a look at schema mapping examples in [this blog post](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading). Cheers!

Comment: I added -delim "," -header true -m '0=col1, 1=col2'

Comment: If you have -header then you may not need -m